# Are loops considered "operators"?

Tags: javascript

At a javascript tutorial website that everyone knows and some use as a reference, it is stated that conditionals are considered "operators".  Another person here at stackoverflow also confirmed this for me a while back.

Loops kind of behave similar to conditionals in that they are not "objects" and that they run blocks of code *with a twist*, and I've been wondering if loops, like the for loop and the while loop and do while loop are considered "operators" or if they are just considered "loops", something categorically independent.

I tried looking here, in various manuals and tutorial sites and found no information, sorry if this is a base question.

Comment: Loops are just loops (control flow statements) that uses operators(comma, increment, decrement)...!

Comment: You need to provide a reference. There is a [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) `? :` that replaces a simple `if..else` statement. There are `for` and `for..in` statements that do loops and methods like *Array.prototype.forEach* that do loops. They're not operators, they're statements or methods as their name suggests.

Answer (score 3):

> At a javascript tutorial website that everyone knows and some use as a reference, it is stated that conditionals are considered "operators".

It’s wrong! (W3Schools is wrong a lot. Is it W3Schools? Stop using W3Schools as a reference.)

They’re simply called “statements” by the ECMAScript standard. “Control statements” is also correct, among some other names, none of which is “operators”.

Comment: Perhaps they meant the `?:` operator?

Comment: @Jack: Ah, good point. In that case, Allan Socks: `?:` is an operator because it can be used in an expression (for one). Loops and `if` statements can’t be.

Comment: Although it is not necessary for an operator to be usable as an expression - e.g. some languages' assignment operator is not usable as an expression. (Although there is no such example in JavaScript, that I know of, where an operator cannot be used as an expression.)

Comment: Thank you guys, you helped clear that up for me.  I guess the ?: is considered an "operator" (ternary operator) and conditionals are "control statements".  Got it.  I think this was my error, not w3schools.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AllanSocks—`? :` is the [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12). The word "ternary" doesn't appear anywhere in the language specification, though `? :` peforms a [*ternary operation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator).

Answer (score 2):

Loops are control-flow statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll make note of this.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in layman terms, it's most likely to be an operator if either of the following makes sense:

```
// unary
a = <operator> <operand>;

// binary
a = <operand> <operator> <operand>;

// ternary
a = <operand> <operator> <operand> <operand>;
```

For example, this doesn't make sense:

```
a = while (i > 0) {
    --i;
}
```

But this does:

```
a = 1 == 3;         // == is a (binary) operator
a = 5 > 4 ? 1 : -1; // ?: is a (ternary) operator
```